# How to delete a django object from multi-form button submission?

Tags: django, forms, python-requests, django-csrf

Im working on a django app and im fairly sure ive got this wrong but i cant workout how to delete a django object from a form button. Ive got the edit/update fields working but im not sure how to use the same form (or the one below it) to also process a delete. my experience with django is limited and i havent setup the logging yet properly. Ive tried the below. What am i doing wrong? the

**Model:**

```
class Tier(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=800, verbose_name='Description')
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Price')
    can_message = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tier_user')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Tier ' + str(self.number)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        amount = Tier.objects.filter(user=self.user).count()
        self.number = amount + 1
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        tier = instance
        tier.delete()
```

**EditTierForm:**

```
         <div>
         <form method="post" action="" role="form" class="col s12">
                <h4>Edit Tier</h4>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12>">
                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Save
                    <i class="material-icons right">add</i>
                </button>
            </div>
         </form>
         <form action="{% url 'delete-tier' tier_id=tier.number %}" method="delete" role="form" class="col s12">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="input-field col s12>">
                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn red" type="submit" name="action">Delete Tier
                <i class="material-icons left">delete</i>
                </button>
              </div>
         </form>
         </div>
```

**urls:**

```
    path('mytiers/', TiersList, name='mytiers'),
    path('mytiers/edit/<int:tier_id>', EditTier, name='edit-tier'),
    path('mytiers/delete/<int:tier_id>', DeleteTier, name='delete-tier'),
    # path('mytiers/delete/(?P<int:tier_id>[0-9]+)/$', DeleteTier, name='delete-tier'),
```

**Views:**

```
def EditTier(request, tier_id):

    tier = get_object_or_404(Tier, id=tier_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditTierForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = tier)
        if form.is_valid():
            tier.price = form.cleaned_data.get('price')
            tier.description = form.cleaned_data.get('description')
            tier.can_message = form.cleaned_data.get('can_message')
            tier.save()
            return redirect('mytiers')
    else:
        form = EditTierForm(instance = tier)

    context = {
        'form':form,
    }

    return render(request, 'edittier.html', context, tier)


def DeleteTier(request, tier_id):
    tier = get_object_or_404(Tier, id=tier_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
           tier.delete()

    context = {
        'form':form,
    }

    return redirect('mytiers')
```

at the moment i keep getting a `Reverse for 'delete-tier' with keyword arguments '{'tier_id': ''}' not found.` error. so i dont think the tier id is passing on. but i cant seem to get it working no matter what i try.

Comment: HTML forms support only GET and POST methods. So that is wrong. Also you have a context object in your method but you're redirecting so that makes no sense either.

Comment: And you can't have the same url pointing to two different methods.

Comment: And if you have `name='delete-tier'` in your url's definition, in your template you must do insert the url in your template like so:  `action="{% url 'delete-tier' tier_id=tier.number %}"`

Comment: thanks @EneP . tho even after correcting those, still not passing the id on `Reverse for 'delete-tier' with keyword arguments '{'tier_id': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['tiers/mytiers/delete/(?P<tier_id>[0-9]+)$', 'sub/mytiers/delete/(?P<tier_id>[0-9]+)$']`

Comment: which is the error thrown when i load edit-tier. which otherwise works without the delete method/routing.